# Shared Java Classes on Cloud

Tags: grails, dynamic, plugins, classloader

My Grails application uses the `dynamic-domain-plugin`. This plugin generates domain classes dynamically. Is it possible for the generated classes be in a single **"shared class server"** and be available across all servers?

If so, can you point me where to look or at least to have an idea on how Java class loading works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make classes available on remote sites. I have detailed how this can work for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419908/java-partial-serialization-of-classes-not-objects). I think you problem is the same, if not, please comment and I will adapt the answer